# Not able to call IBEP20 method from another contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I am working on a smart contract, but when calling one of the methods of another contract (which is IBEP20 token), I am getting the below error:

Error:

> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

Trimmed contract:

```
interface IBEP20 {
// methods 
}

contract TestContract {

    address public constant stakeTokenAddr = 0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82;
    uint256 public __TESTVAR;

    function  __testFunction() external {
        __TESTVAR = IBEP20(stakeTokenAddr).balanceOf(0x51Ea633faE8a74765aeeb50cdc288d1eCFdfc590);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Can't see any issue. Are you trying to call the method sending some BNB?

Comment: is that contract working? it could probably paused

Comment: Got it working now, some issue with the way it was called from remix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now, some issue with the way it was called from remix